# following chainlink fulfilling-requests doc doesn't work

Tags: chainlink

We had setup the chainlink node on gcp and following https://docs.chain.link/docs/fulfilling-requests/. The job is not fulfilled and the currentprice property always returns 0.

Oracle: https://remix.ethereum.org/#url=https://docs.chain.link/samples/NodeOperators/Oracle.sol&optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.6.6+commit.6c089d02.js
Consumer: https://remix.ethereum.org/#url=https://docs.chain.link/samples/APIRequests/ATestnetConsumer.sol&optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.js

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for making this. Can you be more explicit with your question? Did you see the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62162248/11969592

Comment: We missed to remove "-" from the external job id. It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, When we create new job on node it assign externalJobId to job which is like '07269a61-586c-4831-bc26-7d2b581fbd1c'. But when you call function in consumer contract you have to provide this externalJobId in function without dashes so it will be like '07269a61586c4831bc267d2b581fbd1c'.
This is not mentioned in chainlink docs in noticeable way

https://docs.chain.link/docs/fulfilling-requests/

[image]